# How can I use MapLabel in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, google-maps

I am displaying the multiple polygons on map, and I want to display text on top off polygons so I got to know that with Map Label we can display text on above polygons but I lost between while implementing the Map Label(even I didn't find any NPM also)

I am attaching stack blitz URL for reference :- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-draw-polygon-google-maps-d4xnxq?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Please help me in these issue,

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The [Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Utilities doc](https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library#:%7E:text=Archive-,The,-following%20packages%20have) said that the MapLabel is included to packages that are never been officially published and are not maintained. You can open an issue on the github link to prioritize its inclusion.

A workaround that we can use is using a Marker object with an invisible image as an icon then use the label property to put the label you want to use in your polygon. This will look like the label is for the polygon.

Here is a code snippet and [sample code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-draw-polygon-google-maps-q1lwht?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts) modified in your drawPolygon function where the image I used("https://ibb.co/cJpsnpb") is an invisible image:

```
  drawPolygon() {
    const lat_lng = { lat: 66.7225378417214, lng: -155.04016191014387 };
    const map = new google.maps.Map(
      document.getElementById('map') as HTMLElement,
      {
        center: lat_lng,
        zoom: 7,
        mapTypeControl: true,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
          mapTypeIds: ['roadmap'],
        },
      }
    );
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    this.mapIcons.data.forEach((poly, i) => {
      let polygonsMap = new google.maps.Polygon({
        map: map,
        paths: poly.polygons,
        strokeColor: '#FF8C00',
        fillColor: '#FF8C00',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
      });
      google.maps.event.addListener(polygonsMap, 'click', function (event) {
        infowindow.setContent(poly.locator);
        infowindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
        infowindow.open(map);
      });
      polygonsMap.setMap(map);
       var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
       for (let i = 0; i < poly.polygons.length; i++) {
       bounds.extend(poly.polygons[i]);
     }
      var myLatlng = bounds.getCenter();

      const image =
      "https://ibb.co/cJpsnpb";
    const beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      label: {
        text: poly.name,
        color: 'black',
        fontSize: "48px"
      },
      map,
      icon: image,
    });


      
    });
  }
```

Comment: Hi @Pagemag, Its working fine...Thanks for your time and effort.